# Elite Farming Breakpoints

Tags: new-world

I am trying to find information on the breakpoints for elite farming group size for each different elite zone.

Does group size affect the drop rate of loot on bosses in elite zones?

If it does, what are the group size break points and how much do those sizes affect the drop rate?

Sources, please.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is any variance in size based on the zone, but for boss kills, only 5 people are guaranteed loot drops.